# Changing the Background color for post in Blogspot?

Tags: html, css, blogger, blogger-dynamic-views

I just happened to start writing a blog .I have created the blog using the google Blogger .  But i am stuck at a small problem .

I have applied a background  image for the entire blog . But , my posts all have background image as white . Can any one help in removing the background-color for individual posts .  Note that , none of my posts have used the background-color in html . I mean to say , I am not setting any background & that tag is not visible in the html source .
I have tried appending few css to the blogspot .But , none worked . Can anyone help me out ?

Link to my blog is; http://www.kiran9k99.blogspot.in

Comment: Try going into the template options inside Blogger to do this.

Comment: @Paulie_D : already tried that , but didnt work !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just added `!important` at the end, that works.

```
body {
   background: url("//themes.googleusercontent.com/image?id=1oeu82iUqJps3FeKBKTo6YByCaGWa2WjDK-Xuw8Oz9vVaPtbZKzSOJjMoCJYo3C4_-ATJ") no-repeat fixed center top rgba(207, 226, 243, 1) !important;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Please don't ask people to accept/vote. That is entirely up to them, and they get reminders by the system about it.